# change array Items dynamically in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i want to create timeline in angular. in this timeline years change with mouse wheel event.for mouse wheel event i use [hamster.js](http://github.com/monospaced/hamster.js) library. How to change array items by mouse wheel event? 
here is my code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller("Slider", function ($scope) {
var mouseWheel= document.getElementById('slider');

var hammer1 = Hamster(mouseWheel);
$scope.state = { zoom: 1, top: 0 };
$scope.dragY = 0;
 $scope._calc = function(state) {
    var years = [];
    var top = $scope.state.top;
    for (var i = -4000; i <= 2015; i += state.zoom) {
        var obj = {top: top, year: i};
        years.push(obj);
        top += 40;
    }
    return years;
}
$scope.years = $scope._calc($scope.state);
    hammer1.wheel(function(event, delta){
        if (delta > 0) {
          $scope.zoomOut();  // this function not working
        } else if (delta < 0) {
                $scope.zoomIn();   
        }
    });
$scope.zoomOut= function () {
    $scope.state.zoom += 10;
    $scope.years = $scope._calc($scope.state);
};
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call `$scope.$digest();` or `$scope.$apply();` so angular knows that it should rerender:

```
hammer1.wheel(function(event, delta){
        if (delta > 0) {
          $scope.zoomOut();  // this function not working
        } else if (delta < 0) {
          $scope.zoomIn();   
        }
        $scope.$digest();
    });
```

See also [digest and apply explained in detail](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that your Hamster callback does not trigger a digest. Try using $scope.$apply():

```
hammer1.wheel(function(event, delta){
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        if (delta > 0) {
            $scope.zoomOut();  // this function not working
        } else if (delta < 0) {
            $scope.zoomIn();   
        }
    }
});
```